# Converting Highest value of rows to 1 and rest to 0

Tags: r, replace, max

I wasn't sure if creating an if statement would be the best way, but I need code to identify the column with the highest rowmax and replace it with a 1 and the other columns of that specific row get replaced with a 0. I have about 5,000 lines of code.

I am trying to find the row with the highest max value (dataframe) and need to replace the highest row max value with a 1 and the other values with a 0 ( 6 variables/columns with 5,000 rows/obs.)

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It will be much easier for people to give you useful suggestions that fit your situation if you can make your question reproducible. That means including code that generates some sample data, an explanation of what you want done (you sort of have this part but I'd appreciate more explanation), and the specific output you expect if the code is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I added a link to a sample set of numbers I created. Essentially, I want to know what could be done to find the maximum value in Row 1 across (in this case) 4 columns and replace the largest value with a 1 and the other values with a 0.

Comment: So in row 1 across columns A, B, C, and D the largest value is 181 in Column D. I want to replace that 181 with a 1 and replace the other numbers with a 0. Reason I am asking is for BISG proxy information for race and ethnicity probabilities

Comment: `t(apply(as.matrix(your_data), 1, function(x) as.integer(x == max(x))))`

Comment: Generally, questions will get much warmer reception if (a) you provide sample data in valid R syntax---share code to create a few rows of sample data, or use e.g. `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` to generate that code (we can't debug code using a picture as input), and (b) show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should have included code to get sample data and what I have tried so far. I'll do this next time. The code works, I added it as new columns to my data frame and now can just c+paste to original excel sheet (mydata = subset(Coapp_proxy, select = -c(0,7)). Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach in **base R** (similar to what *Gregor Thomas* already posted):

Generate example data:

```
df <- data.frame("row1" = c(1,2,3),
           "row2" = c(1,2,3),
           "row3" = c(1,99,3))

  row1 row2 row3
1    1    1    1
2    2    2   99
3    3    3    3
```

Proposed solution:

```
result <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(x == max(x), 1, 0)))

     row1 row2 row3
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

Conversion back to your exact input data format:

```
as.data.frame(result, row.names = rownames(df), colnames = names(df))

  row1 row2 row3
1    1    1    1
2    0    0    1
3    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> rowwise() |>
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric),~{
  1L*(.x == max(c_across(where(is.numeric))) )
  })) |> ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another potential option, with thanks to OliverHennhoefer for the example data:

```r
df <- data.frame("row1" = c(1,2,3),
                 "row2" = c(1,2,3),
                 "row3" = c(1,99,3))

result <- df == do.call(pmax, df)
df[result] <- 1
df[!result] <- 0
df
#>   row1 row2 row3
#> 1    1    1    1
#> 2    0    0    1
#> 3    1    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>